# Mathematical expectation of the number of points for Poisson stohastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I need to find mathematical expectation of the number of points of Poisson process with parameter $\lambda > 0$ such that: these points $\in [1,2]$ and there are no points of Poisson process in their  left $\delta$ neighborhood, where $\delta \in (0,1)$.
What i mean is: find mathematical expectancy of the number of points such that:
for example: if a is the point, then there are not points of Poisson process in $(a - \delta, a)$
and a should be in $[1,2]$

UPD: am i right that the answer is 0, because $N_{t} \in Z$, hence it cannot have values in (0,1) or (1,2)?

Comment: Let $\mathcal P_\lambda(\{k\})$ be the probability that there are $k$ events in the interval $I$. Then we have that the probability that there are $k$ events in the Interval $J\subseteq I$ is  $\mathcal P_{\lambda\cdot \frac{|J|}{|I|}}(\{k\})$. Further we have that if $J$ and $J'$ are disjunct, then the probability that there are $k$ events in $J$ and $k'$ events in $J'$ is simply $\mathcal P_{\lambda\cdot \frac{|J|}{|I|}}(\{k\})\cdot \mathcal P_{\lambda\cdot \frac{|J'|}{|I|}}(\{k'\})$.

Comment: Using this you can calculate the probablity density function of $\mathcal P_\lambda$ for a fixed $k$. You can now calculate the wanted probability as the integral of a (variable) product of density functions. However, I doubt there's a general closed form for that formula, and even for a fixed $\delta$ there might not be more to do than numerically approximate the integral.